# Apache cxf carriage return issue on tomcat 8.5

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, soap, cxf

When calling a soap xml service (JAX-WS, JAVA 8, SPRING 3) i have a nullPointerException at :
org.codehaus.stax2.ri.evt.EntityReferenceEventImpl.getName(EntityReferenceEventImpl.java:38)

- cxf-bundle-jaxrs 2.4.9
- woodstox-core-asl 4.1.4
- stax2-api 3.1.1

This issue occured when there is a carriage return in the description's value :

```
<ns3:description>
               Bonjour
    <soap:Fault>
        <faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Fault occurred while processing.</faultstring>
    </soap:Fault>
</ns3:description>
```

Machine info :

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server" 
VERSION="7.5 (Maipo)" 
ID_LIKE="fedora" 
VERSION_ID="7.5" 
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.5 (Maipo)" 
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.5:GA:server"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7" 
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.5 
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux" 
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.5"
```

Tomcat info:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.5.31
Server built:   Apr 27 2018 20:24:25 UTC
Server number:  8.5.31.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     3.10.0-862.3.2.el7.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_171-b10
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Can you remove carriage returns / new line characters from the descrption's value before sending the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8188080) in the version openjdk 1.8.0.171 i'am using 1.8.0.181 and it's good